# Quelle est la différence entre « c'est ce à quoi je pense tout le temps » et « c'est ce que je pense tout le temps » ?

Tags: sens, verbes

Laquelle de ces phrases est la plus utilisée ? Y a-t-il une différence d'usage ou de sens ?
Sont-elles interchangeables ?

> C'est ce à quoi je pense tout le temps
>
> C'est ce que je pense tout le temps.

Answer (score 5):

Ce sont différentes formes du verbes *penser*, qui n'expriment pas exactement la même chose.

*C'est ce à quoi je pense tout le temps* : dans ce cas, on parle d'une chose que l'on a en tête sans interruption, tirant presque à l'obsession.

*C'est ce que je pense tout le temps* : je ne vois pas vraiment de contexte dans lequel cela pourrait être dit, on utiliserait plus *C'est ce que j'ai toujours pensé*. En tout cas, cela fait alors référence à une opinion, un avis, une croyance.

Ces deux phrases ont donc un sens différent, et ne sont pas interchangeables.

Comment: Surprise chez google. **"C'est ce que je pense"** est beaucoup utilisé (361 millions d'occurrences d'après Google) notamment comme une forme synonyme de _"à mon avis"_, ou _"d'après moi"_. Et **"C'est ce à quoi je pense"** donne 2 millions d'occurrences. Je pensais comme @Alexis Pigeon à des résultats inverses (peut-être dû à un usage vraiment moderne du français?). Il apparait également que ces deux formes auxquelles on associe _"tout le temps"_ ne sont quasiment pas employées.

Comment: C'est simple, inversons le problème. Tout est plus clair lorsqu'on pose la question "À quoi penses-tu?" ou l'autre "Que penses-tu?". L'explication d'Alexis prend alors tout son sens. Je citerai mon ancien professeur de philosophie, en rappelant que dire "Je pense" n'est pas du tout pareil que "Je pense que". L'un est hautement introverti et aux accents philosophiques quand l'autre relève tout simplement du don d'opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Je vois une nuance :

- C'est ce que je pense : dénote une opinion, un avis.
- C'est à quoi je pense : indique un sujet, une idée en général.

Pour moi, les phrases ne sont pas interchangeables, j'utiliserais la première pour donner mon avis, et sinon la deuxième. Les Français aiment bien donner leur avis, cela explique sans doute que la première version soit plus usitée ! :)