# Doubled elements

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions

J'ai rencontré récemment une phrase comme la suivante dans un texte que j'ai relu il y a peu (je ne me rappelle pas de la formulation exacte de la phrase) :

> Pensez **à à** quoi ressemble cette image.

J'étais certain que ça ne marchait pas, mais trouver la meilleure solution n'est pas facile...

Quelques options rudimentaires :

> (Pensez à la question) : À quoi cette image ressemble-t-elle ?
>
> Déterminez à quoi ressemble cette image.
>
> Trouvez une ressemblance entre cette image et quelque chose d'autre.

Aucun de ces choix n'est parfait, à mon avis, parce qu'on doit effectuer un changement de structure un peu trop profond. Que proposeriez-vous ?

*P.S. Feel free to answer in English :)*

Comment: Pensez à « à quoi ressemble cette image ».

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Pensez à ce à quoi ressemble cette image.*

Comment: Quite broken :-)

Comment: Je me suis demandé si ce choix marcherait, mais je l'avais oublié lorsque je formulais cette question. Je savais que "ce à quoi" marchait, mais je n'étais pas certain de la viabilité de "à ce à quoi". Comme linguee.fr en donne [assez](http://ow.ly/8tMY308Hn0I) d'exemplaires [sensés](http://ow.ly/oBXE308Hn1f) et [Ngrams](http://ow.ly/C9Zh308HmYg) également, je crois qu'il serait acceptable. Et comme ce choix n'exige qu'un petit changement de structure il est préférable pour moi en relecteur. Merci !

Comment: @Frank What do you mean by "broken" ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat - I would be surprised if a native speaker used that outside of trying to be "smart", and then, it doesn't feel "correct". Maybe it is, but if it is, it's really _tiré par les cheveux_. And it doesn't sound good. In any case, the reader/listener has to pause and seriously think about it, to parse it and then to decide if it's correct or not. Maybe you can make a case it is actually grammatically correct - maybe it is - but it's really too _tordu_ to be "good French".

Comment: I'm surprised it's marked as the answer. Maybe it explains that "à à", but we should make sure it is grammatically correct, then dismiss it as not recommendable, in favor of _Posez-vous cette question: À quoi cette image ressemble-t-elle?_, which is perfectly recommendable :-)

Comment: @Frank It's doesn't sound as weird to me, I wouldn't have to pause to understand. Sure, it's not that natural spoken language but fits well for something written. But your comment is interesting, I agree it's not the all-time perfect solution, you should probably have said that instead of just saying it's broken ^^ And I think OP accepted it because it does sound like correct French (*ce à quoi* exists outside of this) and it solves his problem without stretching too far.

Comment: @Frank While this is grammatically correct to me, there's a slight difference in meaning with the original sentence. See [here](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6977/quelle-est-la-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-cest-ce-%C3%A0-quoi-je-pense-tout-le-temps-et-c), "*ce que je pense*" and "*ce à quoi je pense*" are slightly different.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat - OK - can you explain the difference in more details?

Comment: "*Ce à quoi ressemble cette image*" implies it's definite, and you already know it. Like "*Répétez-moi **ce que** vous a dit l'inspecteur*", you're supposed to know exactly. "*À quoi ressemble cette image ?*" is more vague, lets you have mutliple answers and doesn't imply there's a correct one. That's just my opinion, I'm not as definite on this as on *penser qqch* vs *penser à qqch*

Comment: Yes, both the tone and the implication (lack of a foreknown target) of "Posez-vous cette question : ..." are not as close to the original, which  make a difference forme  en tant que relecteur. If I were shown a great reason to dismiss the examples found in Ngrams that seem to correspond exactly to the use case here, I would switch to that as a good alternative, but as it stands, I'm fairly satisfied even if it doesn't roll off the tongue.

Comment: (And I seem to remember that it was a foreknown target)

Answer (score 3):

Je ne suis pas sûr de bien comprendre la phrase. A première vue, je me suis dit que c'était un typo. Si ce n'est pas un typo, l'auteur veut-il dire:

> Pensez à [à quoi ressemble cette image].

ce qui reviendrait à enjoindre quelqu'un à se poser la question: "*à quoi ressemble cette image?*". Si c'est le cas, je pense que la première option (légèrement modifiée) serait la meilleure:

> Posez-vous cette question: À quoi cette image ressemble-t-elle?

Comment: Oui, cette interprétation-là était aussi la mienne. OK, sauf autres suggestions, merci -- cela aurait marché dans le texte.

Comment: C'est un peu bizarre d'écrire ce "à à", pas très clair en général, et je ne l'avais jamais vu auparavant :-)

Comment: En effet. Google Ngrams donne quelques exemplaires, mais lorsqu'on examine de plus près, c'est du charabia ...

Answer (score 3):

On peut parfois faire suivre ces deux prépositions si la deuxième fait partie d'un tout que l'on ne veut ou ne peut pas diviser :

> *Pensez à « À quoi ressemble cette image ? »*

> *Vous pensez à « À l'abordage ! » ?*

> *...environ 2500 mots sont compris par l'enfant de 6 ans. On peut estimer **à à peu près** la moitié le nombre de mots qui figurent à son répertoire.* Jean-Adolphe Rondal, *Votre enfant apprend à parler*, p 69, 1998.

Le *à* saute parfois:

> Pensez à « La recherche du temps perdu ».

Comment: Dans le dernier exemple, une bonne partie des lecteurs parlent de « La recherche » même en dehors du contexte de l'haplologie.

Comment: @GAMPUB C'est vrai, donc du coup « La Recherche ».