# Putting two prepositions next to each other

Tags: grammaire, expressions, prépositions, pronoms-relatifs

Is it possible to put two prepositions next to each other in the following manner?

*Je ne me souviens pas de à qui il parlait.*

Comment: Oh lordy, I forgot that my mod close instantly decides it. Can you tell me whether this answers your question? If so I'll close it as a duplicate: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24578/doubled-elements

Comment: It recommends the use of indefinite relative pronouns but I don't think that can be used to refer to a personal noun.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Your question was about à + à. This is not that.

Comment: @ShakirRather I think it would still offer a solution: de celui à qui il parlait

Comment: If your question is about the construction in general: yes, you can put two prepositions next to each other. For example, *Les patates sont tombées de sur la table* (the potatoes fell off the table) or *Il est sorti de sous la table* (He came out from under the table). If it is about "proper" French, then you might want to avoid your example in formal writing but it would be ok in "standard" French.

Answer (score 5):

La phrase

> Je ne me souviens pas de à qui il parlait.

se rencontre parfois à l'oral, mais n'est pas académique, ignorant l'élision et n'évitant pas la succession de prépositions.

On entend un peu plus souvent :

> Je ne me souviens pas d'à qui il parlait.

qui n'est pas non plus acceptée par la norme.

L'absence de *de* peut choquer car on se souvient normalement **de** quelque chose :

> Je ne me souviens pas à qui il parlait.

Une solution simple ne mécontentant personne est :

> Je ne me souviens pas de **la personne** à qui il parlait.

Le premier *de* disparaît quand s'il est suivi de *d'où* :

> Je ne me souviens pas <s>de</s> d'où il vient.

On peut quand même avoir *de* suivi d'une préposition si cette dernière fait partie d'une locution ou à perdu autrement son statut :

> Je ne me souviens pas d'À la claire fontaine.

> Je ne me souviens pas de de Gaulle...

> Je ne me souviens pas de D'où viens-tu Johnny?

> Les lecteurs potentiels de *À qui la fortune sourit* proviendront d'un vaste public.

*À qui la fortune sourit*, Laurence Mussio, 2020

D'autres successions de prépositions sont courantes, au moins à l'oral :

> T'as pas idée **d'à** qui t'as affaire...

[image]
*Room Service*, Elvin Post, 2010

> Je ne me souviens pas **de par** où je suis passé.

[image]
*Jean Trémolières*, Collectif.

[image]
Jacques Blaize, *Du fondement à l'inachevé*, 2002

> "Je n'ai pas eu le droit d'aller en acheter parce que j'avais mon matériel de vote, je n'ai donc pas la moindre idée **de pour** qui j'ai voté”

*Le nouvel économiste*, 2016

Comment: Aucune de ces phrases ne me semble valide. Donnez au moins *une seule* bonne raison de juxtaposer deux prépositions.

Comment: @SxEequals10nminus2n Toutes ces phrases sont parfaitement compréhensibles et peuvent s'entendre plus ou moins fréquemment. La langue précède la grammaire, elle n'a donc pas besoin de se justifier vis à vis d'elle. Ce qui compte quand on s'exprime, c'est d'abord l'intelligibilité, pas le respect des normes. Quand la norme finit par ne plus correspondre à l'usage, c'est la norme qui évolue, pas le contraire.

Comment: La cooccurrence *de à qui* est parfaitement incompréhensible, et, malheureusement invraisemblable.

Comment: Les autres termes sont plus ou moins formés par amalgame (grammaire),
e.g., d'où, d'à comme dans « la personne d'à côté » à la différence
fondammentale qu'il s'agit de locutions prépositionnelles ou adverbiales.

Comment: @SxEequals10nminus2n Même si elle peut surprendre, la phrase *Je ne me souviens pas de à qui il parlait* est compréhensible pour tout francophone, sauf s'il met de la mauvaise volonté. J'ai bien indiqué qu'elle n'est pas académique et que *...pas d'à qui il parlait* sera plus souvent utilisé.

Answer (score 3):

In the case you provide, no, this is not possible, and  this type of construction (any pair of preposition one after the other) is not found often. This practice of using two successive prepositions is found in the ancient tongue (17th, 18th and 19th century (for instance "*de à qui*").

However, this does not mean that two prepositions in a succession are not found; you do find quite a few and their meaning is according to the combination of the two; nevertheless, they are not analysed as two prepositions any more but as a prepositional locution.

For instance you still find "**de avec**" (written "d'avec"), a prepositional locution.

[réf. 1, 1988](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ubpcAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22d%27avec%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22d%27avec%22) Aller en Angleterre, c'est signaler la rupture d'avec ce passé , coupure qu'avait marquée, dans son oeuvre, Les Caves du Vatican .

[réf. 2, 1936](https://books.google.fr/books?id=GVjQAAAAMAAJ&q=%22d%27avec%22&dq=%22d%27avec%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR4aHZoI_sAhXox4UKHfofCm04ZBDoATAAegQIABAC) […]et s'étant toujours défendu contre ce genre de dépendance en cherchant et en marquant ses différences d'avec autrui

[réf. 3, 1958](https://books.google.fr/books?id=C9qwAAAAIAAJ&q=%22d%27avec%22&dq=%22d%27avec%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR4aHZoI_sAhXox4UKHfofCm04ZBDoATASegQIQRAC) Le procédé de séparation du vanadium d'avec le fer, préconisé par D.

[réf. 4, 1981](https://books.google.fr/books?id=f_rhAAAAMAAJ&q=%22d%27avec%22&dq=%22d%27avec%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR4aHZoI_sAhXox4UKHfofCm04ZBDoATAbegQITxAC) Une évolution similaire apparaissait dans la séparation d'avec le monde et l'appartenance au groupement

On emploi  toujours beaucoup "**de après**", écrit "d'après", but this is not considered as two prepositions any more; the two of them form a prepositional locution.

"De derrière" is another one that is mostly a usage of the past but that you'll find in certain expressions such as "**de derrière les fagots**" and (colloquial) "**idée de derrière la tête**". This combination is not considered as that of two prepositions but is recorded in the TLFi as a locution.

[ref. 1, 1959](https://books.google.fr/books?id=8YUHAQAAIAAJ&pg=PP5&dq=%22de+derri%C3%A8re%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj22qyupY_sAhV0CmMBHXrcD2QQ6AEwF3oECEMQAg) De Derrière les Fagots

[réf. 2, 1976](https://books.google.fr/books?id=CqpYDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT1&dq=%22de+derri%C3%A8re%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj22qyupY_sAhV0CmMBHXrcD2QQ6AEwA3oECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22de%20derri%C3%A8re%22&f=false) Connaissez-vous les meilleures histoires drôles qu'a rapportées Armand Isnard de derrière le rideau de fer ?

[réf. 3, 2013](https://books.google.fr/books?id=oROHAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT148&dq=%22de+derri%C3%A8re%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj22qyupY_sAhV0CmMBHXrcD2QQ6AEwP3oECDAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22de%20derri%C3%A8re%22&f=false) De fines volutes de fumée bleutée s'élevèrent bientôt. Puis, de derrière les cabanes qui longeaient le rempart sud surgirent des silhouettes rapides et furtives qui s'élancèrent vers l'espace découvert.

[réf. 4, 2017](http://www.clg-village-trappes.ac-versailles.fr/spip.php?article412) Exposition "Quelques nouvelles de derrière les barreaux". mercredi 22 novembre 2017

Some combinations are quite common, as for example "**près de**", which is sometimes shortened as "près" ; however, this combination is considered to be one unique preposition, called a "locution prepositive".

Comment: Would "Je souffre **d'au** moins 3 maladies" be a permitted use closer to what OP is asking about?

Comment: @PapaPoule "D'au moins" is quite common ([Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22d%27au%20moins%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)); however, considering it to be a case of two successive preposition is not likely to be the going analysis, this coincidence being best acknowledged, I believe, as a fossilized characteristic; rather, we'd say that there is here the succession of a preposition and of an adverbial locution ("à le moins", contracted as "au moins").

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion, especially about English; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113583/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-putting-two-prepositions-next-to-each-other).

Comment: Il ne s'agit pas de deux prépositions mais d'une locution prépositionnelle. En bref, vous êtes passé à côté du problème en multipliant *inutilement* les exemples. Idem pour la mention **non corroborée** concernant ces usages présupposés, aux siècles passés.

Comment: @SxEequals10nminus2n Je ne suis passé à côté d'aucun problème ; il importe de savoir dans la question de  ce qu'il  ressort de deux mots juxtaposés qui sont apparemment des prépositions, si oui ou non il s'agit de deux prépositions ; je n'ai que commis l'erreur de ne pas m'apercevoir qu' il s'agissait de locutions et non de combinaisons de prépositions analysées séparément.

Answer (score 2):

No, it must be one of these two:

Example One

1. **Je ne me souviens pas de qui il parlait**
2. **Je ne me souviens pas à qui il parlait**.

Translation:

1. I don't remember **who he was talking about**. [formal: about whom he was talking]
2. I don't remember **who he was talking to.** [formal: to whom he was talking]

Example Two:
3) I don't remember **about whom he spoke**.
4) I don't remember **to whom he spoke.**

Translation:

1. Je ne me souviens pas **de qui il a parlé**.
2. Je ne me souviens pas **à qui il a parlé.**

Meaning: to whom he spoke/was speaking
or
about whom he spoke/was speaking.

**Even in English**, you can't have: **of to he was speaking**. [buzzer]

Note: the French imperfect here is past continuous in English. It is not simple past.

Comment: Shouldn't it be " about whom he spoke or to whom he spoke"? Check the correspondence. And is " Je ne me souviens pas contre quoi ils protestaient." correct grammatically?

Comment: @ShakirRather Yes, it is correct

Comment: @ShakirRather Check the correspondence? What does that mean? The French imperfect is not always simple past in English: A qui tu parlais quand je suis entré? Who were you speaking to when I came in.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for the answer! What I meant by "check the correspondence" was for you to make sure that "de qui il parlait ou à qui il parlait" is translated as " about whom he spoke or to whom he spoke" rather than "to whom he spoke or about whom he spoke." Nonetheless, I am glad you cleared my confusion.

Comment: It is obvious that the matter in the OP's question is not  the syntax of "parler **de** quelqu'un" but that of "**parler **à** quelqu'un"; you'd do well not to put the sentence "1." on the same footing as "2."; a parenthesis or a note would be fine and so, while  keeping to the point, you'd still add an interesting detail.

Comment: @LPH This is what the OP said: Je ne me souviens pas *de à* qui il parlait. And s/he wants to know if that's "possible". I believe I answered the question very thoroughly. You can have **de** or **à**, not both.

Comment: @ShakirRather The imperfect **here is not simple past**. **It is past continuous**.

Comment: Why would you use "à" in "parler **de** qqc/qqn"? There is no point in that. It seems to me that "à qui il parlait" is taken for granted, meaning "personne(s) particulière(s) qui était l'interlocuteur". Given that can we combine that with a verb that calls for a preposition which will have to be juxtaposed? That is, as I see it, the one and only question.